# How to have VIM automatically log files that were changed in a logfile?

Tags: unix, vim, logging, hook

Is there anyway to hook into vim's file save action to have it automatically write a log file the name of any file that has been changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's a feature called autocommands. Type `:help :autocmd` to access the documentation. You probably want something like this:

```
:autocmd BufWrite * <command that appends to log>
```

You can use `%` as a placeholder for the current file name.

Comment: I tried doing what you said using 
autocmd BufWrite * <echo %+"\n" >> /home/spyware/code/firmware/current/bin/svn_edit>
so that it could write the current file name to the svn_edit file, but it fails. is there something else that goes in the command syntax?

Comment: I used angle brackets to mark that as a placeholder for a vim command. Sorry if it caused confusion. To run a shell command, you can use `:!`, like this `:autocmd BufWrite * :!echo %+"\n" >> logfile`.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, @chustar `%` should not be used in a shell command unless you want problems with filenames with spaces (or with quotes if you put it inside them). Correct solution is `:autocmd BufWrite * :execute "!echo ".shellescape(expand('<afile>'), 1)." >> /path/to/logfile"`, or even `:autocmd BufWrite * redir >> /path/to/logfile | echo expand('<afile>') | redir END` (it is system-independent and does not require to call external process).

Comment: @ZyX - your code:

`:autocmd BufWrite * redir >> /path/to/logfile | echo expand('<afile>') | redir END`

works fine, but how can the text be completely suppressed from the console? (if I change the `BufWrite` to `BufRead`?) Ideally I'd also want to echo the date along with the filename too.  Do you know how to do this such that there isn't any prompting to the user?

thanks!

Comment: @Stuart Powers To avoid echoing something into vim you should add `silent` before echo (it will still echo to location defined by `:redir`, this use case is even mentioned in `:h :sil`). To add the date you may use `localtime()`->`strftime()`->`expr-.` (these are help tags). If log is kept small by something like `logrotate`, then you could use `call writefile(readfile("/path/to/logfile","b")+[localtime().expand('<afile>')],"/path/to/logfile","b")`: it would not echo anything. Beware that there is only one redir active at a time, so autocommand with `:redir` will blow up any other redirection.